# How to split this partition table using values less than and not get ORA-00906

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, table-partitioning

I would like to ask you for help, I've been looking for an example for days and I haven't found anything that works.

I have a partitioned table in Oracle 11g and these are its last two partitions.
P2026 and P_OTHER , dataType NUMBER(4). This table does not have any column with a DATE type

```
PARTITION "P2026"  VALUES LESS THAN (2027)
 ( SUBPARTITION "P2026_SP0"  VALUES (0) ,
  SUBPARTITION "P2026_SP1"  VALUES (1) ,
  SUBPARTITION "P2026_SP2"  VALUES (2) ,
  SUBPARTITION "P2026_SP3"  VALUES (3) ,
  SUBPARTITION "P2026_SP4"  VALUES (4) ,
  SUBPARTITION "P2026_SP5"  VALUES (5) ,
  SUBPARTITION "P2026_SP6"  VALUES (6) ,
  SUBPARTITION "P2026_SP7"  VALUES (7) ,
  SUBPARTITION "P2026_SP8"  VALUES (8) ,
  SUBPARTITION "P2026_SP9"  VALUES (9) ,
  SUBPARTITION "P2026_SP_OTHER"  VALUES (DEFAULT) ) ,
 PARTITION "P_OTHER"  VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
 ( SUBPARTITION "P_OTHER_SP0"  VALUES (0) ,
  SUBPARTITION "P_OTHER_SP1"  VALUES (1) ,
  SUBPARTITION "P_OTHER_SP2"  VALUES (2) ,
  SUBPARTITION "P_OTHER_SP3"  VALUES (3) ,
  SUBPARTITION "P_OTHER_SP4"  VALUES (4) ,
  SUBPARTITION "P_OTHER_SP5"  VALUES (5) ,
  SUBPARTITION "P_OTHER_SP6"  VALUES (6) ,
  SUBPARTITION "P_OTHER_SP7"  VALUES (7) ,
  SUBPARTITION "P_OTHER_SP8"  VALUES (8) ,
  SUBPARTITION "P_OTHER_SP9"  VALUES (9) ,
  SUBPARTITION "P_OTHER_SP_OTHER"  VALUES (DEFAULT) ) ) ;
```

I want to split P_OTHER to add partitions corresponding to the number that represents the year 2027

I try this:

```
ALTER TABLE "OWNER"."PARTITIONEDTABLE" SPLIT PARTITION P_OTHER VALUES LESS THAN (2028) 
 (SUBPARTITION "P2027_SP0"  VALUES (0) ,
  SUBPARTITION "P2027_SP1"  VALUES (1) ,
  SUBPARTITION "P2027_SP2"  VALUES (2) ,
  SUBPARTITION "P2027_SP3"  VALUES (3) ,
  SUBPARTITION "P2027_SP4"  VALUES (4) ,
  SUBPARTITION "P2027_SP5"  VALUES (5) ,
  SUBPARTITION "P2027_SP6"  VALUES (6) ,
  SUBPARTITION "P2027_SP7"  VALUES (7) ,
  SUBPARTITION "P2027_SP8"  VALUES (8) ,
  SUBPARTITION "P2027_SP9"  VALUES (9) ,
  SUBPARTITION "P2027_SP_OTHER" VALUES (DEFAULT)
  )
INTO (partition P2027, partition P_OTHER);
```

and I get;

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis
```

I tried making just the partition without the subpartitions to add them later and I also have the same error

```
ALTER TABLE "OWNER"."PARTITIONEDTABLE" SPLIT PARTITION P_OTHER VALUES LESS THAN (2028) INTO (partition P2027, partition P_OTHER);
```

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis
```

Does anyone know what the syntax error would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes Oracle's errors in parsing SQL are not very helpful. In this case it isn't about missing parentheses.

You need to use the `AT` clause, not `VALUES LESS THAN`. Also, you don't list the subpartitions when splitting. The syntax for splitting partitions would need to be simply:

```
ALTER TABLE tmp1 SPLIT PARTITION "P_OTHER" AT (2028) INTO (PARTITION "P2027", PARTITION "P_OTHER")
```

You may want to consider interval partitioning, however. If you dropped the `P_OTHER` partition and then set an interval of `(1)` (as your *year* column is clearly a numeric which would increment by one each year; for real date columns it would be `(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1,'YEAR'))` ), Oracle would automatically add new yearly partitions when they are needed, removing the need to expensive splits:

```
alter table tmp1 drop partition p_other;
alter table tmp1 set interval(1);
```

No more splits! The only draw-back is you lose the nice partition names (they'll be system-generated). But since you won't need to do any more partition maintenance, it's not a big deal (and if you ever did need to script some partition work that was date-specific you can use the newish `FOR` syntax partition referencing).